# Normal scaling of the mesh on the surface of an object

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am a novice and want to scale the mesh on the surface of an object along its surface normal. I tried the nodes and they seemed to have some effect,[image] but when I switched to another mesh, it didn't work,I hope someone can help me, thank you very much.
I'm very sorry, it was my negligence not to use English.
[This is the BLENDER file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TljMeSFJ9-vwFhNf6gES7mgL_TMt-gw7/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: The language of this platform is English. I don't think many people understand what nodes are in the screenshot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the screenshots should be in english as well.

Comment: It's really easy to switch interface language to English for taking the screenshot...

Comment: Agreed..thank you for posting the text in English, but please change the language in the screenshots, too. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/68463/35559, and others.

Comment: You have to sample the normals of nearest surface then use it in scale or offest fields

Comment: so I suggest to sample the point aswell abs use that as the center of the scale elements. though, I'm not sure exactly, but I think that mesh island and selection islands are treated as "elements" and there's could only have one central and axis, so this node might not work for the purposes you want, and you might have to recreate this behavior with 'vector math' nodes and a 'set position' node ( - should just be 3 'vector math' nodes, 2 'vector rotate's, a position node, and a 'set position' node. if your interested, let me know. )

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I still don't know what to do. I uploaded the BLENDER file, could you please modify it? Thank you.

Comment: @gangzhou the file is not public. You need to change the permissions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to handle these things

Comment: have a look here: https://workspacetips.io/tips/drive/share-a-google-drive-file-publicly/

Comment: Thank you, my Google Drive interface seems different. I tried to adjust it, is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, it's okay now. The file can be downloaded :-) -- About your question: You want to scale object A, the "ribbon", along the surface normals of object B, the "bean". I am not sure if you can make it work like this. I think you need to extrude/move the outer faces of the ribbon along the normals so that the objects still touch each other.

Comment: Thank you, yes, but I can't do it

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot]

I would delete the outer faces to make the "3 (ribbon)" object flat. You have already selected these faces in your file. Simply delete them. Then select everything that is left and flip the faces (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Flip*) so that the normals point outwards. It should look like in my screenshot (upper right corner).

Now you can use a *Extrude Mesh* node on the "1 (bean)" object to extrude the "3 (ribbon)" object. The node uses the *ribbon*'s normals by default. Since your *ribbon* already follows the *bean's* surface you don't need to sample the surface normals. Choose an *Offset Scale* value (e.g. `0.700`) and untick the `[_] Individual` checkbox to merge the faces (otherwise, you will get a "hair strand" effect).

Comment: Actually, the "bean" in the first screenshot looks more like a bacterium with all its stings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'll give it a try

Comment: Thank you,may be my expression was not good enough. What I meant was that there were many objects(3 (ribbon)）on the surface of 1 (bean), . I wanted to scale the height of 3 (ribbon) along the normal direction of the surface of 1 (bean), but 3 (ribbon) was still tightly attached to 1 (bean), similar to the bacteria with all its stings in the picture